# How can I have two different _GET? (php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin)

Tags: php

```
<?php 

$mysql_pekare=mysqli_connect("localhost", "1","2", "3") or die(mysqli_error($mysql_pekare));

if(!empty($_GET['name'])) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO Personinfo(`Personname`, `Personage`) VALUES('$_GET[namn]', '$_GET[age]')";

    if (!mysqli_query($mysql_pekare,$query)) {  
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($mysql_pekare)); 
    }
    echo "Welcome ". $_GET["namn"]; 
}

?>

<form id="Personinfo" action="index.php" > <!-- default form method is GET -->
<input type="text" id="namn" name="namn" placeholder="namn"/>
<input type="text" id="age" name="age" placeholder="age"/> 
<input type="submit"/>
</form>

</body>
<body>


<?php 

$mysql_pekare=mysqli_connect("localhost", "1","2", "3") or die(mysqli_error($mysql_pekare));

if(!empty($_GET['Product'])) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO Produkter(`ProduktNamn`, `ProduktPris`) VALUES('$_GET[Product]', '$_GET[Price]')";

    if (!mysqli_query($mysql_pekare,$query)) {  
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($mysql_pekare));  
    }
}

?>

<form id="Produkter" action="index.php" > <!-- default form method is GET -->
<input type="text" id="Product" name="Product" placeholder="Produkt"   />
<input type="text" id="Price" name="Price" placeholder="Pris"/> 
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: You will not be able to get a proper answer without including some sample code and output/errors

Comment: Note that `$_GET` is not a command, but a global variable, and commonly is not set by programmer, but is populated by variables sent with _GET_ method

Comment: What is your problem? form1 vs form2? (PersonInfo / Produkter)

Comment: when i enter either of the "questions" i get this: 
Notice: Undefined index: namn in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/index.php on line 51

Notice: Undefined index: age in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/index.php on line 51

Comment: i guess i just have to change $_GET variable to something else on the second one

Comment: Don't change your question to match the answer. How are readers supposed to understand what the answer was fixing?

Comment: You have a typo: `empty($_GET['name']` change `name` in `namn `

Comment: Oh ok. Just trying to show progress. Still problem still remains

Comment: @William.John Add the revised code to the question without removing the original.

Comment: works man thanks alot dude. sry for being slow. very new to php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two forms with different input names, so you can check for these names, instead of generic `$_GET`:

```
if( isset( $_GET['namn'] ) )
{
    (...)
}
elseif( isset( $_GET['Product'] ) )
{
    (...)
}
```

If you want be more *chic*, you can identify different forms through an hidden `<input>` identifier:

```
<form id="Personinfo" action="index.php" >  
<input type="hidden" name="formID" value="Personinfo"/>
(...)
<form id="Produkter" action="index.php" >
<input type="hidden" name="formID" value="Produkter"/>
(...)
```

and in you php code, check for this:

```
if( isset( $_GET['Personinfo'] ) )
{
    (...)
}
elseif( isset( $_GET['Produkter'] ) )
{
    (...)
}
```

Comment: so replace that with if(!empty($GET))  ?

Comment: @William.John you can also use ` !empty($_GET[namn]) ` instead of `isset( $_GET['namn'] )` // **Please note:** I have typos in my answer! use `isset` **without** exclamation poit! I'm sorry.

Comment: i get this: Notice: Use of undefined constant name - assumed 'name' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/index.php on line 50

Comment: with the if !empty($_GET[namn]) solution

Comment: @William.John You forgot the commas: ` $_GET['namn'] ` (actually 
I was the one that I forget in the comment!)

Comment: Nice it works!  echo "Welcome ". $_GET["namn"];  this doesnt work though.

Comment: You have submitted Personinfo form?

Comment: yeah, "name and age"

Comment: I have tested now with copy-and-paste **without any modification** and it works fine for me. Are you sure is the complete code? Try to replace double-commas with single-commas, but I don't think that this is the problem. What you mean with “only 1 of them works now” ?

Comment: @William.John I rolled back your changes. If you want to show updated code, add it as an `EDIT` at the end of the question.

Comment: Ok thanks! I am new here so I will get better in the future.

Comment: @William.John It's good practice to modify question adding information or more original code, but without **modify** code. Questions remains online, and if the code change visitors do not understand anything! :)